Determining Transformations Between Stabilizer Generators for Large Qubit Systems
I’m currently exploring stabilizer states in quantum computing and have a specific question regarding the transformation of stabilizer generators.
For example, consider the initial stabilizer generator set s = <XX, ZZ>, which corresponds to a Bell state. If I have another stabilizer generator set s' = <ZX, XZ>, I know that the operator needed to transform ( s ) to ( s' ) is a Hadamard gate applied to the second qubit.
It can solve these transformations by hand for small numbers of qubits, but increasingly challenging to do so as the number of qubits increases.
My question is: Is there a deterministic method or algorithm available to systematically identify the operations required to transform one stabilizer generator set into another for larger systems? Any insights or references to relevant literature would be nice too.
